# Django images in template through FK

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using a detail view to show data and I have 2 models.

The problem is that one is FK of another and that ones storing pics and I need to show them.
Can't find the solution. Because of the Detail view.

//HTML FILE THAT DISPLAYS THE PICTURES//
file.html

```
{{object.hall_address}} ,{{object.hall_city}}<br>

I {{object.hall_owner}}, heartly invite you to have a great time.<br>



{% comment %} {% if object.images.hall_pic0 or object.images.hall_pic1 or object.images.hall_pic2 or object.images.hall_pic3 %}

<img src="{{object.images.hall_pic0.url}}" class="w3-circle" style="width:400px" alt="11"><hr width="15%">

<img src="{{object.HallProperties.hall_pic1.url}}" class="w3-round" style="width:400px" alt=""><hr width="15%">

<img src="{{object.HallProperties.hall_pic2.url}}" class="w3-round" style="width:400px" alt=""><hr width="15%">

<img src="{{object.HallProperties.hall_pic3.url}}" class="w3-round" style="width:400px" alt=""><br>




</div>


{% else %}
{% endif %} {% endcomment %}


{% for pictures in object.hallpictures_set %}
<img src="{{ pictures.hall_pic0.url }}" class="w3-circle" style="width:400px" alt=""><hr width="15%"></div><div class="zoom1">
<img src="{{ pictures.hall_pic1.url }}" class="w3-circle" style="width:400px" alt=""><hr width="15%"></div><div class="zoom1">
...
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

view.py

```py
class HallDetail(DetailView):
    model = HallProperties
    template_name='hallfiles/hall-details.html'
```

models.py

```py
class HallProperties(models.Model):
    hall_name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)

    hall_city = models.ForeignKey(CityModel.City, max_length=512)

    hall_owner = models.ForeignKey(
        HallOwnerData, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Hall Owner")

    parking_capacity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Parking Capacity")


class HallPictures(models.Model):

    hall_properties = models.ForeignKey(
        HallProperties, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Hall link")

    hall_pic0 = models.ImageField(
        "Hall Picture 1", upload_to='media/hallpics', blank=True, null=True)

    hall_pic1 = models.ImageField(
        "Hall Picture 2", upload_to='media/hallpics', blank=True, null=True)

    hall_pic2 = models.ImageField(
        "Hall Picture 3", upload_to='media/hallpics', blank=True, null=True)

    hall_pic3 = models.ImageField(
        "Hall Picture 4", upload_to='media/hallpics', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: define the foreignkey relationship in the hallproperties model instead of the hallpictures model

Comment: Pics is a different class

Comment: I know. Instead of a hall_properties field in your HallPictures model, add a hall_pictures field to the HallProperties model with the FK relationship. Then you can access it in your template using {{ object.hall_pictures.hall_pic0.url }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues here. The first one is that `object` is already the HallProperties object; there is no need to put `object.HallProperties`; presumably you have not done so for the other fields such as hall_name and hall_city.

Secondly, a foreign key is a one-to-many relationship. So you have multiple HallPictures items associated with each HallProperties. You would need to iterate through the pictures:

```
{% for pictures in object.hallpictures_set.all %}
<img src="{{ pictures.hall_pic0.url }}" class="w3-circle" style="width:400px" alt=""><hr width="15%"></div><div class="zoom1">
<img src="{{ pictures.hall_pic1.url }}" class="w3-circle" style="width:400px" alt=""><hr width="15%"></div><div class="zoom1">
...
{% endfor %}
```

Note that this structure is very odd. I don't know why you have a separate model, or why it has four separate picture fields on it. The point of having a separate model would be for it to only have a single image, and then your loop would just iterate over each separate object and output the image for each one.

Also note, it is Python and Django style to use singular names for models: HallProperty, HallPicture.

Comment: There is Still No output.

I was using images in my Property class but my senior asked me to use a separate class for technical purposes.

Comment: This will work as long as the models are as shown. What does `{{ object.hallpictures_set.all }}` display? Your "senior" presumably wants what I said, with one picture field per HallPicture.

Comment: Please check the updated version for the entire html file

Comment: I removed it and there's no output except for the text above. Now after removing the related_name field. I'm getting this error **'RelatedManager' object is not iterable**

Comment: Yes, because you have `object.hallpictures_set`, instead of `object.hallpictures_set.all`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add related_name property for hall_properties in HallPictures model.

```
hall_properties = models.ForeignKey(
    HallProperties, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Hall link", related_name='images')
```

After you can access the image of object.

```
object.images.hall_pic0.url
```

Comment: There is no need to define a related name. The default is `hallpictures_set`, which would work fine. However, your code would not work because a reverse relationship gives a queryset, not an instance.

Comment: No result. Same thing